# sp_setapprole taking 100 - 200 ms

Tags: sql-server-2008, performance, security, database-tuning

SQL Server 2008 SP1 here.

We have a machine where sp_setapprole calls take more than 100ms and they are done many times per user operation on an application.

The developer says that in his setup, sp_setapprole calls take less than 1ms. The machine specs are comparable (I have 12GB RAM, 6 cores, he has 16GB and 8 cores).

This problem makes the application performance to be unacceptable.

So, two actual questions:

1.- What are possible causes (and solutions) of slow sp_setapprole?

2.- How would you debug the problem?

Comment: Are all the machines in question on the same network segment? What is the exact call being used, is there any encryption involved?

Comment: Same network segment, no encryption. One exact call: exec sp_unsetapprole @cookie=<cookie_value>

Comment: Not that I have an answer either way but your question says set and the comment above unset. Which is it? Or both? Can you reproduce the problem at will? If so does the spid experience any wait types during the operation?

Comment: Faulty RAID controller...

Answer (score 0):

I used HDTune to test the disks and they had an abysmal 10MB/s read speed. Diagnostics show a faulty RAID controller.